# Declare units to Convert from a string variable

Tags: delphi, measurement

I am using the Convert function within delphi to write a simple multi device application that will allow me to convert measurements.

The form consists of 2 Comboboxes and en edit. To select Conversion From, Conversion To and a value.

So in my comboboxes i select the units then i pass the value of the comboboxes to 2 global strings

```
  fromType := cbConvFrom.Selected.Text;
  toType := cbConvTo.Selected.Text;
```

Which return the following.

```
cbConvFrom returns duCentimeters
cbConvTo returns duMeters
```

However when i try to pass these values into a Convert function obviously they do not work as i am trying to pass a String as a TConvType, Shown below

```
conversion := Convert(StrToFloat(editValue.Text), fromType, toType);
```

How can i use these strings as a TConvType so the code above will work correctly.

Comment: I doubt you can perform that conversion without generating a map. Why do you want to show those internal variable names to your users. Surely cm is better than duCentimeters?

Comment: The comboboxes actually do show CM/M etc to the user. Just when a unit is selected duCentimeters is stored in a string as that is the part i need to perform Convert

Comment: That string is useless to you. Store the integer value of the variable with that name. Or, better, pass cm or m and let the framework convert for you. Try reading the documentation. Makes things much easier when you do that.

Comment: How would i do that. Sorry i am very new at this.

Comment: You are asking how to read or find the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Drop using string representation of conversion types and use descriptions instead. Get the descriptions from the registration of the type, using [`ConvTypeToDescription`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.ConvUtils.ConvTypeToDescription). Eg:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(ConvTypeToDescription(duMeters));
ComboBox1.Items.Add(ConvTypeToDescription(duCentimeters));
```

Then you can use the [inverse](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.ConvUtils.DescriptionToConvType) to provide to the conversion function.

```
DescriptionToConvType(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex], fromType);
DescriptionToConvType(ComboBox2.Items[ComboBox2.ItemIndex], toType);
conversion := Convert(StrToFloat(editValue.Text), fromType, toType);
```